# Problemas al evitar la carga de varios Gifs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gif

gracias a esta página obtuve un código para evitar las cargas de un Gif, a menos que la persona desee cargarlo. El código funciona como quiero, pero al agregar varios de estos códigos empiezo a tener problemas con los puntajes de Google, puedo agregar hasta 3 y mantener 100 puntos, pero en cuanto agrego unos pocos mas mi puntaje baja hasta 57 puntos.

```js
function loadPage7(){var frame = $('#frame7');var url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/TId0pOVWwpGmxMGYKc/giphy.gif';frame.attr('src',url).show();}

function loadPage6(){var frame = $('#frame6');var url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/S7F2YVJjwPRMHxL3jE/giphy.gif';frame.attr('src',url).show();}

function loadPage5(){var frame = $('#frame5');var url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/cmZ6Gy17JRhmXp1UEP/giphy.gif';frame.attr('src',url).show();}

function loadPage4(){var frame = $('#frame4');var url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/UVLxwG2NQwtU89QtnK/giphy.gif';frame.attr('src',url).show();}

function loadPage3(){var frame = $('#frame3');var url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/S3WPsFyHf8yVWj9WNU/giphy.gif';frame.attr('src',url).show();}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner1" onclick="loadPage7()">
Mostrar Gif
</div>
<center>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="360" id="frame7" style="display: none;" width="480"></iframe></center>

<div class="banner1" onclick="loadPage6()">
Mostrar Gif
</div>
<center>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="360" id="frame6" style="display: none;" width="480"></iframe></center>

<div class="banner1" onclick="loadPage5()">
Mostrar Gif
</div>
<center>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="360" id="frame5" style="display: none;" width="480"></iframe></center>

<div class="banner1" onclick="loadPage4()">
Mostrar Gif
</div>
<center>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="360" id="frame4" style="display: none;" width="480"></iframe></center>

<div class="banner1" onclick="loadPage3()">
Mostrar Gif
<center>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="360" id="frame3" style="display: none;" width="480"></iframe></center>

... tengo agregado otros 2 mas, pero para no hacer tan largo el código
```

Al probarlo aquí produce error el **$**, pero lo puse tal cual esta en mi pagina y funciona, no tengo mucha idea de js más que modificar lo básico. Mi duda es ¿Tener el mismo código repetido produce tantos problemas? ¿O lo que sucede es que los gif se están cargando aunque no lo parezca?. Necesitaria saber esas respuestas, pero si alguno puede juntar el js en un solo cuerpo y que yo pueda agregar los frame que desee me seria util.

Comment: El problema del `$` es por que tienes que añadir la libreria de `JQuery` al snippet, se añade a la izquierda cuando estas editando el código. Respecto al problema, ¿Has probado a cambiar las etiquetas `<iframe></iframe>` por `<img/>` ?

Comment: No soy un experto en SEO, pero leyendo por ahí he visto en varios sitios que copiar el contenido de otras páginas incide en un puntuaje negativo en Google. Para descartar que a San Google le moleste ver muchas etiquetas `<iframe>` podrías, en vez de tenerlos vacíos y luego mediante **JS** darles un atributo `src`, generar el `<iframe>` por completo desde **JS** así, al cargar la página Google no vería esa gran cantidad de `<iframe>` cargados y sin enlaces.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @phpMyGuel básicamente el mismo código pero agregando src al iframe, verdad? entendiéndolo así y probando esa forma empeora ya que esta cargando todos los gifs | Edit: ¿O solo agregar src sin url?

Comment: No no. Tú ahora mismo tienes cargados `<iframe>` en el HTML, y luego a estos, con **JS** les metes un atributo `src`. Yo lo que te propongo es que no pintes en el **HTML** nada del `<iframe>` y lo que hagas sea crear el elemento `<iframe>` dinamicamente desde **JS** para luego colgarlo en el **DOM**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mis comentarios me refería a hacer algo como esto:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor-banner">
  <div class="banner1" onclick="loadPage7()">
    Mostrar Gif
  </div>
<div>

<script>
 
  function loadPage7() {
    var html = '<iframe src="https://media.giphy.com/media/TId0pOVWwpGmxMGYKc/giphy.gif" frameborder="0" height="360" id="frame7" width="480"></iframe>';
    
    $('.contenedor-banner').append(html);
  }
  
</script>
```

Como ves, inicialmente en el **HTML** no hay ningún `<iframe>`, dado que el encargado de construirlo es la función que llamas desde el evento `onclick`. De esta manera, cuando cargas la página, que es cuando Google analiza el contenido de esta, no existe ningún `<iframe>` cargado, por lo que presumiblemente debería de solucionarte el problema.

Eso deberías hacerlo con cada uno de los `<iframes>` que necesitas cargar en la página.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @phpMyGuel, entendi lo que decias pero no sabia como hacerlo debido a que no se casi nada de js, pero entendiendo que debía evitar los iframes gracias a ti, buscando bastante encontré un js que me simplifica la vida y no afecta la carga de la página ni la puntuación de google.

```js
(function($) {

 var getGif = function() {
  var gif = [];
  $('img').each(function() {
   var data = $(this).data('alt');
   gif.push(data);
  });
  return gif;
 }

 var gif = getGif();

 var image = [];

 $.each(gif, function(index) {
  image[index]     = new Image();
  image[index].src = gif[index];
 });

 $('figure').on('click', function() {

  var $this   = $(this),
    $index  = $this.index(),
    
    $img    = $this.children('img'),
    $imgSrc = $img.attr('src'),
    $imgAlt = $img.attr('data-alt'),
    $imgExt = $imgAlt.split('.');
    
  if($imgExt[1] === 'gif') {
   $img.attr('src', $img.data('alt')).attr('data-alt', $imgSrc);
  } else {
   $img.attr('src', $imgAlt).attr('data-alt', $img.data('alt'));
  }

  $this.toggleClass('play');

 });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
<img alt="Static Image" data-alt="imagen gif.gif" height="360" src="cualquier imagen que represente el gif.jpg" width="480" />
</figure>
```

Con esto podemos agregar gif a deseo sin modificar el js, incluso podemos jugar con el css modificando `figure` agregando algún indicador de play.